# Can someone tell me what the striked out COBOL code means in this screenshot?

Tags: ide, cobol

This is code loaded into the Micro Focus Visual COBOL IDE.

[image: https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4318/35327251834_eec1a81d8a.jpg]

Comment: There is no cobol tag because programming questions are off-topic on [su]

Comment: Setting the length (# of bytes) of each field in the 173 byte record

Comment: Please post code as text, not as picture.

Comment: Actually this is a tools question: "What does the striked out COBOL code means in this screenshot?" (and this won't be shown in the text).
It likely means that the sub-items of CUSTOMER-RECORD aren't referenced anywhere.

Comment: @SimonSobisch Ah, so the actual question is "Can someone tell me what it means that the code is striked out" - which is a different question than the one stated.

Comment: Some work with Google suggests that the strikeouts indicate unused variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My research has shown that it means the variables aren't being used.